# Pytorch: Google cloud storage, persistent disk for training models on DLVM?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pytorch, google-cloud-storage, bucket, persistent-storage

I'm wondering what's the best way to go about
a)reading in the data
b)writing data while training a model?

My data is in GCS bucket, about 1TB, from a dataflow job.

For writing data (all I want is model checkpoints, and logs) do people just write to a zonal persistent disk? Don't write to google cloud storage. it is a large model so the checkpoints take up a fair bit of space.

I can't seem to write data to cloud storage, without writing say a context manager and byte string code all the places I want to write.

Now for reading in data:
pytorch doesn't have a good way to read in the data from GCS bucket like tensorflow?
So what should I do, I've tride gcsfuse which I think could work, when I 'mount' the bucket, I can only see inside the repo I selected, not sub directories. Is this normal?

would gcsfuse be the right way to load in data from GCS?

Thanks.

Comment: Did you try using GCS SDK for reading from and writing to GCS?